# What is the difference between enable_cloudwatch_logs_exports and neptune_enable_audit_log

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-neptune

While working with a neptune database cluster in AWS, I found that there are multiple options for enabling audit logging for the neptune cluster; [enable_cloudwatch_logs_exports](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/neptune_cluster#enable_cloudwatch_logs_exports) and [neptune_enable_audit_log](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/auditing.html) in [aws_neptune_cluster_parameter_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/neptune_cluster_parameter_group#example-usage).

I've not been able to find anything in the documentation that describes the difference between these values shown in the examples below. From my observations the two values control separate settings, but from the outside they appear to define the same setting? Is one applieda the cluster level, and applied directly to the underlying readers/writers?

Cluster resource option:

```
resource "aws_neptune_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  enable_cloudwatch_logs_exports       = ["audit"]
  neptune_cluster_parameter_group_name = aws_neptune_cluster_parameter_group.my_param_group.name
...
}
```

Parameter group setting:

```
resource "aws_neptune_cluster_parameter_group" "my_param_group" {
  parameter {
    name  = "neptune_enable_audit_log"
    value = 1
  }
...
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/auditing.html), you need to enable audit logging on the DB parameter group and then you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two separate settings for using Audit Logs in Neptune.  Enabling them via the parameter group is required to turn on audit logging for all instances in a cluster.  Once audit logs are enabled, they are stored locally on the instance by default.  The only way to access them from here is to use the Amazon Neptune console.

If you want to export Audit Logs to CloudWatch (for better visibility and parsing/searching) you can also set the cluster resource parameter for `enable_cloudwatch_logs_exports` to export these logs to CloudWatch.